# Is it really harmless to use sizeof(p[0]) no matter initialized or not?

Tags: c++, sizeof

I was arguing with one of my friends, if we have defined an array/pointer:

```
sometype * p;
```

if we want to know the size of the type, he said one should use:

```
sizeof(sometype)
```

I said one could also use:

```
sizeof(p[0]),
```

it should be the same. He disagreed, and his point is if `p` is not initialized, then this usage of `p[0]` may cause problems.

But to my knowledge, only when we change or depend on the value of `p[0]`, will this be harmful. Since we don't change `p[0]` nor use `p[0]`'s value, this is totally sensible.

Since we can't persuade each other, can anyone make this concept clear.

I know this question is of no use, and almost all the developers will use sizeof(sometype), including me :). But this question is fun and I'm really curious to know if there is any case that sizeof(p[0]) will be harmful.

=================================
Let me extend this question a little bit. If I do use some irrelevant value (or considered as kind of random or whatever). Can I always use `p[0]` to get a value?

To make the question more clear, If I don't change the value of an uninitialized pointer, just use the value it is pointing to, can I always get a value without causing problems?

Comment: Hamless? That's a shame. I love ham!

Comment: `sizeof p[0]` (or `sizeof *p`) is actually safer, because you might change the type of `p` but forget to change the `sizeof` statement.

Comment: Lol, did I really say hamless? If I did, then sorry about the typo. Funny question, funny typo, though.

Comment: @NikosC Still I'm often talked off when I suggest using `malloc(sizeof *p)` instead of `malloc(sizeof T)`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++ language the argument of `sizeof` is never evaluated, meaning that it is completely irrelevant whether the variables used in the argument expression hold valid values or not. Only the static type of the expression under `sizeof` matters, and it is determined at compile time.

Moreover, it is actually preferable to use expressions (as opposed to type names) as arguments of `sizeof` to make the code more type-independent.

In C the argument expression might be evaluated in some cases (variable-length arrays), but not in C++.

Comment: Good point about VLAs, but I think it would just use the size expression from the declaration, and still not evaluate the operand?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Well, the language says that the expression is *evaluated*, meaning that in case of `int n = 5, i = 0; int a[n][n]; sizeof a[i++];` I would expect `i` to get incremented.

Comment: Interesting bit of C99 trivia, that.  Too bad I can't +1 again.

Comment: @BenVoigt +1 on both your answers =P

Answer (score 10):

The argument to `sizeof` is an *unevaluated operand*, so pointer dereferences and so forth don't have to refer to valid memory.  It's purely based on type information.

(As a corollary, `sizeof *p` is not polymorphic, it uses the static type only.)

Answer (score 8):

`sizeof` is [evaluated at compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2615203/298479) so it does not matter whether the memory is initialized or not since that's a runtime thing.

So `sizeof p[0]` or - what I think is even nicer since it does not look array-ish - `sizeof *p` is a great way to avoid typing the type again when using `sizeof`.

Answer (score 2):

sizeof() is evaluated by the compiler, so uninitialized variables are not an issue.