# Converting an int array to an int value in c

Tags: c

I have an integer array

```
int number[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

What can I do to get int x = 1234?
I need to have a c version of it.

Comment: In a loop: convert to strings, and concatenate them. How else?

Comment: Lookup **positional notation**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
x = 1000*number[0] + 100*number[1] + 10*number[2] + number[3];
```

This is basically how decimal numbers work. A more general version (when you don't know how long 'number' is) would be:

```
int x = 0;
int base = 10;
for(int ii = 0; ii < sizeof(number); ii++) x = base*x + number[ii];
```

Note - if `base` is something other than 10, the above code will still work. Of course, if you printed out `x` with the usual `cout<<x`, you would get a confusing answer. But it might serve you at some other time. Of course you would really want to check that `number[ii]` is between 0 and 9, inclusive - but that's pretty much implied by your question. Still - good programming requires checking, checking, and checking. I'm sure you can add that bit yourself, though.

Comment: +1 for an awesome basic math solution. Can I double upvote? Elegant!

Comment: I would assign sizeof(number) to a variable instead of calculating it every time.

Comment: @nickecarlo - `sizeof` is computed at compile time, so I don't think there's an overhead.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615203/is-sizeof-in-c-evaluated-at-compilation-time-or-run-time

Comment: Heh, thanks. I bought my professors habit as good practice without question.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of how to "shift over" a number to the left by multiplying by ten.  You can think of appending a digit by adding after a shift.

So you effectively end up with a loop where you do `total *= 10` and then `total += number[i]`

Of course this only works if your array is digits, if it is characters you'll want to do `number[i] - '0'` and if it is in a different base you'll want to multiply by a different number (8 for instance if it is octal).

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 0, x = 0;
for(; i < arrSize; i++)
    x = x * 10 + number[i];
```

`x` is the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i;
int x = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    x = ( 10 * x + number[i] );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int number[]={1,2,3,4}
int x=0,temp;
temp=10;
for(i=0;i<number.length;i++)
    {
        x=x*temp+number[i];
    }
cout>>x;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all for your quick replies :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something with a for loop and powers of 10

```
int tens = 1;
int final = 0;
for (int i = arrSize - 1; i <= 0; ++i)
{
    final += tens*number[i];
    tens*=10;
}
return final;
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is quite easy.Just list a complete function here.

```
int toNumber(int number[],arraySize)
{
   int i;
   int value = 0;
   for(i = 0;i < arraySize;i++)
   {
      value *=10;
      value += number[i];
   }
   return value;
}
```