# How to find size of elements pointed by array of pointers?

Tags: c, string, pointers

Here is the code,

```
char const *words[] ={
        "Hello",
        "What are you doing",
        0
    };
    int size = sizeof(words[1]), totalSize = sizeof(words);
```

The `totalSize` is is having the values `24` but `size` is having value `8`. I used gdb to get a run-time look, for the command `p words[1]` result is `$1 = 0x40400f "What are you doing"` so `words[1]` is considered as array by debugger, still `sizeof()` is considering it as pointer. I don't understand why that is.

Comment: `words[1]` is a pointer to a null-terminated string. The size of a pointer on your (64-bit) platform is 8 bytes. The fact that the debugger shows you the contents of the pointed string doesn't mean that the compiler refers to `words[1]` as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the debugger shows you the contents of the pointed string doesn't mean that the compiler refers to it as a **statically allocated array** (for which the `sizeof` operator can be applied "correctly").

You can retrieve those sizes (excluding null characters) using this piece of code:

```
int size = strlen(words[1]);
int totalSize = 0;
for (int i=0; words[i]!=0; i++)
    totalSize += strlen(words[i]);
```

You may as well get rid of that last element in the `words` array, and use this instead:

```
int size = strlen(words[1]);
int totalSize = 0;
for (int i=0; sizeof(words)/sizeof(*words); i++)
    totalSize += strlen(words[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`words` is an array of 3 pointers to (`const`) `char`.

So `sizeof` with the array operand will yield the accumulated size of the 3 pointers and `sizeof` of an array element will yield the size of one pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`words` is an array of `char` pointers. Therefore, its elements are of type *pointers to `char`*. `words[1]` is of type pointer to `char` not an array of `char` and that's why you are getting the size of pointer instead of the size of the string it points to.

> How to find size of elements pointed by array of pointers?

In order to find the size of string that a pointer points to, you need to loop over it.

```
int size = 0;
char const *ptr = words[1];
while(ptr++) 
    size++;
```

or use standard library function `strlen`

```
size_t size = strlen(words[1]);
```

Comment: "*... you need to loop over it.*" or call `strlen()` on it!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `sizeof()` operator is being replaced by the [result at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615203/is-sizeof-in-c-evaluated-at-compilation-time-or-run-time). It should give the same result for all `sizeof(words[i])` if used in a loop for example, so also for `sizeof(words[1])`. So the compiler interprets this simply as a (64-bit) pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You declared array `words` like

```
char const *words[];
```

It means that each element of the array has type `char const *` and `sizeof( words[0] )` is equivalent to `sizeof( char const * )` that is equal in your environment to 8 bytes.
If you want to know the length of the string literal pointed to by pointer `words[0]` then you should use standard C function `strlen` declared in header `<string.h>`. For example

```
size_t length = strlen( words[0] );
```

Take into account that though all pointers in the array have the same size that is 8 bytes string literals pointed to by these pointers have different sizes.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char const *words[] =
    {
        "Hello",
        "What are you doing",
        0
    };

    const char **p = words;

    for ( ; *p; ++p ) printf( "\"%s\": %zu\n", *p, strlen( *p ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
"Hello": 5
"What are you doing": 18
```

The string literals themselves have types in C correspondingly

`char [6]` and `char[19]` because they include the terminating zero.

Answer (score 0):

The initial box shows the base address of the string.

```
+----+    +-----+
|1000|--->|Hello|
+----+    +-----+
words[0]

+----+    +------------------+
|2000|--->|What are you doing|
+----+    +------------------+
words[1]
```

if you perform `sizeof(words[0])`, which is a pointer of type `char const*` and we all know that the size of the pointer remains the same for all data type usually `4`, but in you case its 64 bit machine and hence you are getting `8` as a output.

Even the `sizeof(words[1])` would fetch you `8` for the same reason.

Use a pointer to a pointer concept for fetching the words at that base address.