# Does dereferencing a pointer identifies the object being pointed or returns the value stored in it?

Tags: c, pointers

I have read many books and answers on internet saying that if you derefer a pointer then it will give you the value stored there. But if we consider the code:

```
int x = 3,*ptr;
ptr = &x;
printf("%d",*ptr); /*print value in x*/
printf("%d",sizeof(*ptr));/*gives sizeof of x*/
 printf("%u",&*ptr);/*give address of x*/
```

If dereferencing were to give value stored in x then we would have : sizeof(3) and &3 that does not make sense whatsoever but if it were to return the variable x itself then everything would make sense: &x : gives address of x, sizeof(x) : gives size of x and

```
printf("%d",x); //print value in x.//
```

So my question is what does dereferencing a pointer give the object pointed by it or the value stored in the object?

Comment: sizeof is just operator, [evaluated during compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2615205/5601069) - so you have no address for `x`. Thus it prints size of pointer.

Comment: @Enkeli: it is not always compile-time evaluated.

Comment: Pointers point at allocated objects, not values.

Comment: VLA's definitely cannot be sizedof on during compilation.

Comment: @Lundin : then shouldn't dereferencing return the object rather than the value in it?

Comment: dereferencing does not "return" anything. It is just an lvalue expression.

Comment: @user6112826 Everything inside a computer is either values or addresses. Nothing else exists. The "object" in this case is your variable `x`. By using the pointer `ptr`, you get the address of that object. By using `*ptr` to de-reference, you get the contents of that object. That's it, there's no further magic about it.

Answer (score 2):

What is the difference between "the object" and "the value stored in the object", in your world?

The expression `sizeof (*ptr)`, which can be written `sizeof *ptr`, computes the size of the value of `*ptr`. Since `ptr` has type `int *`, that value has type `int`.

Just because `*ptr` evaluates to `3` doesn't mean it's equivalent with the literal `3`, though, it's a different expression. Taking the address of a literal makes no sense, but you can't just substitute the literal, `&*ptr` is the same as `ptr`, not `&3`.

Comment: So what happens when we do *ptr? If it is not equivalent to 3 then what  is it equivalent to?

Comment: Why must it be "equivalent" to anything like that? Why can't it just mean "the value that the pointer is pointing at", in whatever form makes the most sense in the particular context?