# C++ does sizeof calculate every call if object is static

Tags: c++, static, sizeof

Lets say I have a static array of an object which size cannot change.

```
struct vector2 { //8 Bytes
    float x, y;
};
```

Does the computer calculate the size every time `sizeof` is called or is this stored somewhere? If not, does it have the same performance as it was stored somewhere?

```
std::cout <<  sizeof(vector2) << std::endl;
std::cout <<  sizeof(vector2) << std::endl;
```

**Is this as fast as**

```
Byte sizeOfVector2 = sizeof(vector2);
std::cout <<  sizeOfVector2 << std::endl;
std::cout <<  sizeOfVector2 << std::endl;
```

Comment: sizeof is compile-time operation

Comment: The size of a type in C++ is known at compile time. It's as if replacing the call to sizeof with an integer literal.

Comment: Don't worry about it. *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil."*

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615203/is-sizeof-in-c-evaluated-at-compilation-time-or-run-time

Comment: @BaummitAugen Okay, true, but I didn't even think about that it could be calculated at compiletime.

Comment: I figured. That's why I wrote related, not "duplicate". ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof` is calculated at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof` operator is computed at compile time.

Comment: @hvd correct, didn't notice that, removed it from the answer