# Compile time assertion based on sizeof operator

Tags: c, compiler-errors, assert

Given the fact that `sizeof()` operator is a compile-time operator (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2615205/2162550) StackOverflow accepted answer) I tried to go ahead and implement a compile-time type check based on it.

What I want to achieve is compile-time check for whether or not a parameter is characters array, and if not, than raise a compilation error. My solution is based on the fact that character consume one byte. So I came up with this:

```
#define assert(maybeStr)\
    extern int varaible_not_exist;\
    if (sizeof(maybeStr[0]) != 1)\
    {\
        varaible_not_exist++;\
    }
```

I figured out if `sizeof(maybeStr[0])` is evaluated at compile-time, than the whole `if` can be evaluated at compile-time, which means that in case the `if` statement is false (`maybeStr` is indeed characters array) at compile-time, the `varaible_not_exist++` won't be compiled eventually, and no compilation error will be issued. And vice versa, if the `if` statement is true (`maybeStr` is not characters array) than `varaible_not_exist++` will be compiled and compilation error will be raised.

Long story short, it seems to be working. I only tested it in [online-c-compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) for now, but this macro seems to do the job.

Now, my question is whether or not this macro is solid? I mean is it possible that different compilers and different optimizations flags will yield different result?

Comment: sizeof is compile time except for VLAs.

Comment: If your compiler supports C11, you can use [`_Static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This sounds like a XY-Problem

Comment: you mean a linker error not compilation error right?

Comment: @tkausl i need a compile time assertion for checking whether the type of a parameter is string

Comment: The type of the parameter is in your functions parameter list, I don't see why you need to check it.

Comment: @tkausl the parameter i want to check is a macro parameter (of another macro of course) so no type is explicitly given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean is it possible that different compilers and different optimizations flags will yield different result?

Yes, this is possible. Your code is not reliable.

If your compiler supports C11, you can use a [static assertion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert) instead:

```
#include <assert.h>
...
static_assert(sizeof(maybeStr[0]) == 1, "parameter must be a string");
```

Comment: "Your code is not reliable": I think you mean: if the compiler doesn't perform compile time elimination of the code in the test, then the macro will make the code not compile everytime by not optimizing out the branch. I like the solution, but an explanation why it is not reliable would be a plus (I already voted your answer)