# Get Size of Struct in C

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

How can I get the Size of an struct Pointer..

```
struct person **angest=NULL;
```

In this struct are 22 persons registrar. How can I get the Count 22 with sizeof? It is possible?

Comment: No. How would `sizeof` know (at compile time) the size of where it's pointing to(at runtime)? Also, "In this struct are 22 persons registrar" is wrong, it's clearly a null pointer.

Comment: No. Especially not when it is a pointer to pointer whose value is NULL.

Comment: The struct became the data from an text file at compile time. This is the decleration.

Comment: @Blaze The `sizeof` is not compile time. It can get the size of a VLA.

Comment: @Broman this isn't a VLA though, so it's done at compile time. `sizeof` is only done at runtime for VLAs. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336577/10411602

Comment: @Fkcm95 the compiler knows nothing about the file data, don't confuse the compiler with the IDE which is hosting it.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are allocating the persons using malloc, eg 
`angest=malloc(sizeof(struct person *)*22);` (you have now allocated 22 pointers to the structs)

Then it is not posible to get this number 22 by using `sizeof`. The size of dynamically allocated arrays cannot be calculated in compile time. You must maintain this size yourself, e.g. `static int nPersons;`